# Prove that $A \cap B = B \setminus (\bar{A} \cap B)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

> Let A and B be two random events associated with a random experience.
>   Show that:
>
> $A \cap B = B \setminus (\bar{A} \cap B)$

As stated in the course, given a random event $A$, the definition of $\bar{A}$ is $\Omega \setminus A$. So I thought I could do something like this:
$A \cap B = B \setminus ((\Omega \setminus A) \cap B)$. $(\Omega \setminus B) $ is going to be $B$ since $\Omega$ includes $B$. So the expression becomes: $B \setminus B$ which is $\emptyset$. This is, obviously, a wrong result.

How is this proof done?

Comment: What do you mean with $B\setminus A$? I don't believe that this is true. Consider $A = [0,1], B = [0,2]$. Then $A\cap B = [0,1] = A$. However, $B\setminus (\overline{A}\cap B) = B\setminus [0,1] = (1,2]$.

Comment: @nippon  I can't give you any more information since I don't have it.

Comment: @nippon No $\bar A\cap B = (1,2]$, note that $\bar A$ is the complement of $A$

Comment: @Ove Ahlman That explains a lot, however $\overline{A}$ usually denotes the closure of a set, while $A^{\rm{C}}$ denotes the complement.

Comment: Your assumption/conclusion that $\Omega\setminus B=B$ is quite wrong. How did you reach that? Do you have a definition of set difference to work with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easy way of doing these equalities of sets is to show each direction separately.

First we prove $A\cap B\subseteq B\setminus (\bar A\cap B)$:

If $x\in A\cap B$ then $x\in A$ thus $x\notin \bar A$, hence $x\notin (\bar A\cap B)$. However we know that $x\in B$ as $x\in A\cap B$. Thus $x\in B$ and $x\notin (\bar A\cap B) $ which we can write $x\in B\setminus (\bar A \cap B)$.

Now we prove $A\cap B\supseteq B\setminus (\bar A\cap B)$:

For the other direction assume $x\in B\setminus (\bar A\cap B)$, then $x\notin (\bar A \cap B)$, however we also know $x\in B$, thus we conclude specifically that $x\notin \bar A$. $x\notin \bar A$ however implies that $x\in A$. Hence we know both $x\in A$ and $x\in B$, thus we conclude that $x\in A\cap B$.

As we now know that both $A\cap B\subseteq B\setminus (\bar A\cap B)$ and $A\cap B\supseteq B\setminus (\bar A\cap B)$ hold, we may conclude that $A\cap B= B\setminus (\bar A\cap B)$

Answer (score 2):

A different approach is just write the right side of equality in basic set operations, i.e. rewriting the difference set operator in terms of union, intersection and/or complementarity

$$B-(A^c\cap B)=B\cap (A^c\cap B)^c=B\cap(A\cup B^c)=\\=(B\cap A)\cup(B\cap B^c)=(B\cap A)\cup \emptyset=A\cap B$$

You are using here the definition of difference set operator, the De Morgan law and the distributive law of the intersection over union.